# Changing existing ads to house ads admob

Tags: android, admob

I already have admob ads active on my android app. These were not house ads.
But now, I want to display 'House ads'.

For this I added 'New house ad campaign' for my existing ad unit, following instructions from this link:

[Creating House Ads](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3210442?hl=en)

Added image and associated redirect link.

Enabled it.
For testing purpose I added 1000 impressions for 1 day.
But they aren't displaying. No change to previous ads. I also pause previous ad sources and enabled house ad only, still no change.

I've following questions:

1. Do 'House ads' take time to activate? If yes, how much?
2. When using house ad campaign with 'Impression goal' set, other ads will also display? Like third party ads?

I want these ads to be displayed in Android app.

Looking forward to help. Thanks in advance.